# Jquery function not fired (html injected in second moment)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry for no-too-much clear title.

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap Modal to edit some record.

```
<a class="contact" href="#" data-form="/edit/models/sms/{{ @value['fields']['id'] }}" title="Edit">
       <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
       <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
       <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-stack-1x"></i>
       </span>
 </a>
```

And this is the javascript code that open the Modal:

```
$(".sms-model").click(function(ev) { // for each edit contact url
    ev.preventDefault(); // prevent navigation
    var url = $(this).data("form"); // get the contact form url

    $("#smsModelModal").load(url, function() { // load the url into the modal
        $(this).modal('show'); // display the modal on url load
    });
   $("#smsModelModal").modal('show'); // display the modal on url load
    return false; // prevent the click propagation
});
```

Finally this is the form injected inside the modal:

```
<div class="modal-body">
            <form role="form" method="post" class="sms-model-form" action="{{ @SERVER.REQUEST_URI }}">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend class="sr-only">Edit</legend>
                    <input type="hidden" name="edit_id_model" value="{{ isset(@sms_model) ? @sms_model[0]['fields']['id']['value'] : '' }}" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="title">{{ @lng_label_sms_title }}</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control required-field" name="title" value="{{ isset(@sms_model) ? @sms_model[0]['fields']['title']['value'] : '' }}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="text">{{ @lng_label_sms_text }}</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="text" class="required-field">{{ isset(@sms_model) ? @sms_model[0]['fields']['text']['value'] : '' }}</textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-white pull-right">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> {{ isset(@sms_model) ? @lng_btn_edit : @lng_btn_add }}
                    </button>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Test" />
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Everything functions as a charme. Now I would submit the form via AJAX.

So I'm adding this:

```
$('.sms-model-form').on('submit', function(e) {
        console.log('test on submit....');
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: this.action,
            data: $(this).serialize()+'&ajax=TRUE',
            context: this,
            success: function(data, status) {
                $('#smsModelModal').html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

But form is submitted via regular mode, and not via AJAX. I.e. I don't have neither the event logged in console.

I'm thinking that this is because the form is injected in a second moment in the page and not at

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Am I right? How I can solve my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly need to set up your event handler via delegation:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.sms-model-form', function(e) {
```

That attaches a handler at the root of the DOM to catch bubbling "submit" events. Because you're adding your modal dialog content *after* your code runs, if you do it your way the code will simply have no effect; the `".sms-model-form"` selector will match nothing, so no event handler will be attached anywhere.

Using the above form of `.on()`, you ensure that events involving DOM substructures added dynamically will still be handled as you desire them to be.

Comment: It works like a charme... after that FF clear his cache :)